# Sorting Address data in google sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I have several thousand rows address data,  concatenated in a single field. When i try to sort i get:

- 103 LOWREY AVE S
- 104 CHURCHILL DR
- 104 LOWELL ST N
- 104 MELROSE ST
- 105 ALISON AVE
- 105 ANGELA CRES
- 105 CARMINE CRES
- 105 SALTSMAN DR
- 106 ARGYLE ST N

Is there a way to sort by the street name, then number without breaking apart the data in the single address field?

Comment: No, to sort by some part of the cell you must break that cell apart. You could write a custom sorting function in Apps Script and call it from a macro / menu. In that custom sorter you'd split the cell value on spaces and sort it lexically by everything except the first array element (which is the "106" portion). Obviously if you have complications like "N641 W358 Fake St." then you have to improve your sorting logic.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, *for your example* - because each street name is unique, hence sorting by street number would not affect the order anyway:

```
=ArrayFormula(sort(mid(A1:A9,5,50)))
```

Comment: i should have mentioned that the street number isn't constant in length, it varies from 1-digit to as much as 6-digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SORT(A1:A9,
    INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A9," "),,2),1,
    A1:A9,1)
```

- `SORT` A1:A9 on two sort - criterias:

  - `SPLIT` Col A by space and choose second column with `INDEX`
  - If the street names are same, Sort by `A1:A9`